# gsettings changes are not working over ssh

Tags: ssh, gsettings

I am trying to set the `idle timeout` for `Ubuntu 14.04` using `gsettings` from ssh.

The commands I am using are like this

`dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 600`

`dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 0`

`dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true`

`dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true`

After the commands are executed with various `timeout` periods the changes are taking place, but those timeout changes are getting lost after a reboot or logout.

Is this possible to make the timeout change persistent on reboot/logout.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when you are launching a new dbus instance with `dbus-launch`, you are saving the configurations to the wrong location by kicking off a new dbus. While adding `dbus-launch` to the beginning of the `gsettings` invokation will remove any error messages, you will not save changes.

There exists for the target user an existing dbus process, and via ssh your terminal doesn't receive the correct environment variables with which to address it.

The correct way to edit gsettings via ssh is to first identify the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` of the existing dbus process and set it as an environment variable. Thus:

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ)
# And now:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 600
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Ubuntu 18.04** you have to set not only `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, but also `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. You can do so with this command (replace `121` with UID and `gdm` with user):

```
su gdm -s /bin/bash -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/121 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/121/bus gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay'
```